# xsd validation , provide information about the ids contained under enumeration

Tags: xml, xsd, enumeration

I am using an xsd to validate my xml. One of the element AddressType should contain only one of the values (1,2,3).

```
          <AddressType>1</AddressType>
```

I would like to provide information about this ids. e.g. 1 correspond to Home, 2 correspond to Work, etc.

I thought of using enumeration like this-

```
                <xs:enumeration value="1" id="Home"/>
```

but this will fail if any other enumeration has same id. Is there a way that we can provide value as well as the information about the id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

My first suggestion is not to use id's in XML (XML is human readable ;-)). If you have to then you can use xsd:annotation/xsd:documentation to provide what each of the id's mean.

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what expectations you have for the application that validates your XML, and what exactly you mean by `provide information about these ids`. To enhance error messages? To use it when building data entry forms from XSDs?

One way to do it is to leverage the XML Schema annotation mechanism.

- Validators usually give you access to the particular schema object that was associated with the XML node, in which case you could extract additional information from annotations.
- Other tools that build data entry forms from XSD may be able to show a dropdown where the text comes from annotation and the value from the enumeration's value. These typically come already with recommended markup and how to insert it into XSD.

  ```
      <xs:enumeration value="1">
          <xs:annotation>
              <xs:documentation>Home</xs:documentation>
              <xs:appinfo>
                  <something:proprietary>Home</something:proprietary>
              </xs:appinfo>
          </xs:annotation>
      </xs:enumeration>
  ```